# problems rendering a template when using a decorator in Django

Tags: django, decorator

I have this URL in my project:

```
url(r'^alerts/inbox/$', 'inbox', {'template_name': 'inbox.xhtml' }, name = 'inbox'),
```

The inbox view is exactly this:

```
@login_required()
@ownsBid
def inbox(request, template_name):
    return render_to_response(template_name, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My ownsBid decorator is:

```
def ownsBid(fn):
    def _check(request, *args, **kwargs):
        return fn(request, kwargs)

    return _check
```

When I use:

```
fn(request, kwargs)
```

I get a *TemplateDoesNotExist at /alerts/inbox/*. If I do instead:

```
fn(request, kwargs['template_name'])
```

It renders the template without problems. I don't have a clue why this happens. But if I have to pass a specific parameter to the view, it totally breaks DRY principle of decorators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try `fn(request, **kwargs)` instead? Here is a quick illustration:

```
>>> def foo(template_name):
 print template_name

>>> d = dict(template_name =  'foo/bar.html')
>>> foo(d)
{'template_name': 'foo/bar.html'}
>>> foo(**d)
foo/bar.html
>>>
```

So what is happening here? In the first case (`foo(d)`) you are passing a dictionary as-is to the function. Naturally the value of `template_name` is then the dictionary object.

In the second case (`foo(**d)`) you are <strike>expanding</strike> [unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the dictionary and passing the keys and values as keyword arguments. The `template_name` key will become a keyword argument and `foo/bar.html` will be its value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I missed the asterisks and didn't even notice.